# vba add more than one space in vba email body?

Tags: vba, email, space

I am using vba in outlook to generate an email. I would like to find a way to move some text over to the right, about 100 pixels.

since I don't believe there is a way to incorporate css or styles in vba I am looking for a way to add more than one space to get the text moved over. however when I try space() function and " ", even if I repeat these codes a number of times it only ever gives me one space.

can someone please help me and show me what I need to do, thanks

```
"<br><br><br>" & "3PL & HAULAGE SUPPLIERS: " & " " & "<font size=""4.5"" face=""calibri"" color=""red"">" & "<b>" & EmailCount & "</b></font>" & vbNewLine & _
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add 10 white spaces just before 3PL. You may need to adjust as the pixel distance will be relative to the font

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Sub test()

    Dim WS As String

    WS = "&nbsp"

    For i = 1 To 10
        WS = WS & "&nbsp"
    Next i

    Debug.Print "<br><br><br>" & WS & "3PL & HAULAGE SUPPLIERS: " & " " & "<font size=""4.5"" face=""calibri"" color=""red"">" & "<b>" & EmailCount & "</b></font>" & vbNewLine

End Sub
```

Comment: You can avoid the `for` loop by using the string function

`WS = string(10,"&nbsp")`

Failing that try replacing the `"&nbsp"` with something like `chr(9)`

Comment: @MMerry the above does not work as the string constructor has a syntax of String(Number as Long,Character) this will produce a string consisting of ten ampersands. Replacing the "&nbsp" with Chr(9) also does not work as when the html engine renders the code the leading white spaces will be removed.

Comment: of course, I forgot that string takes a _character_ not a _string_.